# Oracle APEX Selection list

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form on a table with some values (text fields) and a select list. The select list is declared in shared components and shows me values from another table. Also I have some process (after submit) to modify and create new table entry. Everything works fine without propagating values from select list. There are no errors from the process. It looks like the process didn't get a value for :P22_WORKER_LIST from the selection list. It should work when I push the create or save buttons but nothing happened. Every instruction in BEGIN END block runs  great without this one.
Process:

```
BEGIN
<some instructions>
UPDATE "WORKER" SET ACCOUNT_LOGIN = :P22_LOGIN 
     WHERE SURNAME = :P22_WORKER_LIST;
END;
```

Comment: Not clear what you are doing or the problem. Have you checked session state to make sure a value is being set for P22:Worker_list?

Comment: How could I check this session state?

Comment: Read the APEX doc, search for session state. Also, there's this thing called gooogle..

Comment: can you give more info about your pages, it seems you have a config problem at select list, please check default value, source sections of your selectlist and please check the list of values query it should be as select xx  as d , yy as r from your_table. your select list return value might not be SURNAME and that is why that query would not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for suggestion with the session state. After submiting page it turned out that the value for my :P22_WORKER_LIST is a WORKER_ID instead a SURNAME.

```
BEGIN
    <some instructions>
    UPDATE "WORKER" SET ACCOUNT_LOGIN = :P22_LOGIN 
    WHERE WORKER_ID = :P22_WORKER_LIST;
END;
```